# Convert string into variable name in JQuery

Tags: jquery, string, variable-names

Is it possible to convert a string into a variable name while in jQuery's `document.ready`?

If I try this in pure JS

```
var boh = "blahblah";
console.log(window["boh"]);
```

returns `blahblah`, while if I go with JQuery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var boh = "blahblah";
    console.log(window["boh"]);
});
```

returns `undefined`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm getting values from a json and i want those values to become variables i can use within a script. i can do it outside `document.ready`, but i was curious whether it's possible to get them from inside.

Comment: look at this and see if that give some hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611190/passing-variables-in-jquery otherwise let me know

Comment: In your first snippet `boh` is in the global scope, which you should avoid by all means while in the second `boh` is not in the global scope. Within DOM ready you may replace `var boh` with `window.boh` but I see no point in cluttering the global scope. Why do you want to use global variables?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I'm not sure I can fully understand your point @PeterKA. In my script, I'm using them from within a function inside jQuery, so I guess I'm using it locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this without declaring the data type as `var`.

```js
boh = "Pure JS";
console.log(window.boh);

$(document).ready(function() {
  boh1 = "jQuery";
  console.log(window.boh1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript variables are that defined and declared without `var`are under `window` scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So variables declared without var have wider scope, correct?

Comment: yes @ruggerocastagnola. If you declare them with var , then you cant use them as `window.variableName` , you can only us as regular variable